# Log all json objects?

Tags: jquery

In the following code, I want to log all of the objects and their names that are located under data.data.InventoryItems in the `$.get` code
Right now it is returning undefined; though if I use `console.log(data.data.InventoryItems)` under the `$.get`, it returns 13 objects with child objects within them. I want the children to be logged as well; here is my current code; thanks.

```
(function (d, s) {
s = d.createElement('script');
s.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js';
(d.head || d.documentElement).appendChild(s);
s.onload = function () {
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function ($) {
        var url = "http://www.roblox.com/Trade/InventoryHandler.ashx?token=%22&filter=0&userid=1210210&page=1&itemsPerPage=14&_=";

        function getData(link) {
            $.get(link, function(data) {
                for (var property in data.data.InventoryItems) {
                    if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                        console.log(property);
                    }
                }           
            });
        }
        console.log(getData(url));
    });
}
```

})(document);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure what you're trying to achieve here, but this at least logs every DOM-element as a jQuery-object on the page you are currently on:

```
$('*').each(function()
{
   console.log($(this)); 
});
```

Update:

This loop might work for you.

```
for (var property in data) 
{
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) 
    {
        console.log(property);
    }
}
```

Update 2:

You must have 2 loops like so:

```
for (var property in data) 
{
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) 
    {
         for (var subproperty in property) 
         {
             if (property.hasOwnProperty(subproperty)) 
             {
                 console.log(subproperty);
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to log each json object

Comment: @user3786876 Well I have no idea what your request returns right now so can't really help with that.

Comment: It returns a ton of objects; I want it to log them all

Comment: `Object {sl_translate: "message", success: true, msg: "Inventory retreived!", data: Object}`

Comment: I just want it to log all of object's values; how do I make it do that?

Comment: Thanks, it is working now. How do I make it log all of the objects under data.data.InventoryItems?

Comment: @user3786876 Probably with a second loop, but this time with for (var property in data.data.InventoryItems) { ...

Comment: I updated my question a bit to be more specific, think you can update your answer to the question? Thanks, help is appreciated!

Comment: Oh and by the way, that if inside the loop is really important to have. I don't bother explaining it right now, but you should always have it there when looping the object this way.

Comment: Update 2 is just returning numbers, though the objects are strings